# Why does Set#intersection behave differently when passed a Sequence instead of a Set?

Tags: swift, set, sequence

I noticed an odd bug in an app and narrowed it down to a surprising cause: if you pass a sequence to `Set#intersection`, you get different behavior than if you pass a `Set`, even though both are supported methods of the `Set` data structure.

You can verify at any Swift REPL:

```
  1> Set([3, 6, 0, 1, 5, 2, 4]).intersection([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
$R0: Set<Int> = 7 values {
  [0] = 5
  [1] = 0
  [2] = 3
  [3] = 1
  [4] = 2
  [5] = 6
  [6] = 4
}
  2> Set([3, 6, 0, 1, 5, 2, 4]).intersection(Set([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
$R1: Set<Int> = 6 values {
  [0] = 1
  [1] = 5
  [2] = 0
  [3] = 4
  [4] = 2
  [5] = 3
}
```

The issue here is that the first result has an extra value, the integer `6`, even though there is no `6` in the sequence passed to `intersection`. The second result is correct - the first is wrong. And the only difference between the two calls is that the second call has its sequence converted to a `Set`.

Am I losing my mind, or is this unexpected behavior?

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? I cannot reproduce this on Swift 5.5.1.

Comment: 5.6.1 and also in the new beta 5.7

Comment: Appears to be [same as this bug](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/58322)?

Comment: That is one serious bug! Someone needs to improve their unit testing. However, the workaround is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the bug [SR-16061](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/58322). The report shows a similar unexpected behaviour to yours, where using the `Set` overload of `intersection` produces the correct output, but the `Sequence` overload does not.

```
let s = Set("ae")

print("s: \(s)") // ["a", "e"]

let i = s.intersection("aa")
let j = s.intersection(Set("aa"))

print("i: \(i)") // ["a", "e"]
print("j: \(j)") // ["a"]
```

I tried to look a little into what's happened. The previous [commit](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/2e3e88cab8a395e3c6122f173bea3f13861d54b6) that modified the `intersection` methods in NativeSet.swift was back in November 2021. This agrees with the release dates of the Swift version in which this bug can be reproduced - just between Swift 5.5 and 5.6. It is said that this change is supposed to speed up `Set.intersection` by using a bit set.